# Ie8 and below ODDLY ignoring all CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've never run into this before, but upon checking my work

http://ryanspahn.com/avia8/

in ie8 and below I am noticing it completely ignores the css.  The css is being read in other browsers but not in ie8 and below.

I've never seen this before.  Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: What happens if you remove the 2 calls to http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?

Comment: I removed those google web font calls... any different on your end?  Not on my end after clearing my ie cache.  Worked fine yesterday...

Comment: weird it fixes the issue if i put style.css and point to it in the root directory.  weird!

Comment: I hadn't tried, just wondered. I've booted a VM with IE8 running on XP SP3 and it appears the same as when viewing in my OS browser (Iceweasel). Have you changed anything since yesterday, code or on your PC?

Comment: An aside comment: I did notice a few META elements appearing before the HEAD element opens, which you may want to fix

Comment: IE7 is a different matter though.. the page appears vertical. Presumably, you have IE8 in "IE7 mode"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check style.css, line 51:

```
#extra-spacing {
    margin: 17px 0 0 0; 
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;" /* <- extra quote */
}
```

When I removed the extra quote, it worked for me.

---

In the interest of education, this is how I found the problem:

First, I used IE9's developer toolbar (press F12 on the keyboard) to switch the browser mode to IE7.  (IE8 also has the developer toolbar)  Then I looked on the CSS tab and noticed that it was only loading a partial set of rules.  Since it stopped at the `#extra-spacing` rule, I knew there was probably a syntax error there.

Comment: oh darn i completely missed that.  Thank you very much.  That fixed it!